# Bare react native project does not run on ios simulator

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run an a fresh react native project using react native cli but I get the following error:

```
2022-07-22 09:31:45.006 xcodebuild[96346:8084479] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-07-22 09:31:45.006 xcodebuild[96346:8084479] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/ramiel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-dcybszwqvhaflbhahawancnnffvo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SysUio.o /Users/ramiel/Desktop/Typescript/react\ native/AwesomeProject/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'YogaKit' from project 'Pods')
(2 failures)
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: have you properly installed pods ?

Comment: I followed the documentation by using `sudo gem install cocoapods`. is that not how you do it?

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup this should do only. iumm whats your RN version

Comment: yes that is what I followed. It says 0.69.2

Answer (score 0):

install the cocoapods for ios using the command `sudo gem install cocoapods`

after installation navigate to the ios folder and run `pod install`. then you can run your project using `npx react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason. I created a new typescript project and it worked :)